# Pytesseract read coloured text

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to read coloured (red and orange) text with `Pytesseract`.
I tried to not grayscale the image, but that didn't work either.

Images, that it CAN read
[image: IMG 1]
[image: IMG 2]
[image: IMG 3]

Images, that it CANNOT read
[image: IMG 1]
[image: IMG 2]

My current code is:

```py
        tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string(
                    cv2.cvtColor(nm.array(cap), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
                    config="--psm 7")
```

Comment: if your background is always the same then try [background subtraction](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html) before doing the `OCR`.

Comment: A quick goggle for __tesseract improve recognition__ gives many helpful sources of guidance you can find without asking a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little function (below) will do for any color

#### ec9Ut.png

[image]

#### Thresh result

[image]

#### x18MN.png

[image]

#### Thresh result

[image]

#### SFr48.png

[image]

#### Thresh result

[image]

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

def getText(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    HSV_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h,s,v = cv2.split(HSV_img)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(v, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    txt = image_to_string(thresh, config="--psm 6 digits")
    return txt
    

text = getText('ec9Ut.png')
print(text)
text = getText('x18MN.png')
print(text)
text = getText('SFr48.png')
print(text)
```

Output

```
46
31
53
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply:

---

- 1. Erosion
- 2. Adaptive-threshold

---

- [Erosion](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

Erosion will decrease the thickness of the image like:

| Original Image | Erosion |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

When we apply erosion to the 53 and 31 images

| Original Image | Erosion |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

---

- For [adaptive-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3):

  - When `blockSize`= 27

    - | Erosion | Threshold |
      | --- | --- |
      | [image] | [image] |
  - When `blockSize`= 11

    - | Erosion | Threshold |
      | --- | --- |
      | [image] | [image] |

For each image, we need to apply different threhsolding

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img_lst = ["fifty_three.png", "thirty_one.png"]

for img_pth in img_lst:
    img = cv2.imread(img_pth)
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    img = cv2.resize(img, (w*2, h*2))
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    erd = cv2.erode(gry, None, iterations=2)
    if img_pth == "fifty_three.png":
        thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(erd, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 27, 5)
    else:
        thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(erd, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 5)
    txt = image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6 digits")
    print(txt)
    cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

```
53

31
```

---

**Possible Question1:** Why two different block size parameters?

Well, thickness of each image are different. So two different parameters are required for text-recognition.

---

**Possible Question2:** Why `None` defined as kernel for `erode` method?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a suitable kernel for erosion. Therefore I set to None.

---